# Form validation on all inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form and I want to do some checks on all the fields on `keyup`.

Only if all of the inputs are completed, then the message should be displayed.

In JS there's this function called `checkValidity()` which checks if an input is validated, but on my example it doesn't work right.

If I complete the first three fields, that message appears, but I don't want that.

I want that message to appear only when all of the nine fields are completed.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    console.log(input);
    if (!input.checkValidity()) {
      document.querySelector('.message').classList.remove('d-none');
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.message').classList.add('d-none')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="participants-data">
    <div class="form-content-holder">
      <div class="js-form-content form-content">
        <div class="participant-index">Participant</div>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="firstName" fieldName="firstName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" fieldName="lastName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Last Name</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" fieldName="email" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="js-form-content form-content">
        <div class="participant-index">Participant</div>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="firstName" fieldName="firstName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" fieldName="lastName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Last Name</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" fieldName="email" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="js-form-content form-content">
        <div class="participant-index">Participant</div>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="firstName" fieldName="firstName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" fieldName="lastName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Last Name</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" fieldName="email" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message d-none">Validated</div>
</form>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/make96/pen/yLEeMpO?editors=1111

Comment: I'm not sure why it seems to currently checking in batches of 3, but if you want to ensure all fields are valid, you'll need to check them all on each change (Or track a "valid" state for each)

Comment: I would suggest to create a `submit` button instead if you want to display the message or not after all of the nine fields are completed. Also, you should use another methods like `some()` or `every()` as a condition in case others inputs return `false` and some are `true` from `checkValidity()`. `keyup` event is not ideal of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The `label` attribute is intended to be associated with an `input` element of some sort which is done either using the `for=id` type syntax or by wrapping the input inside the label tag and omitting the `for` attribute.You inputs do not have `id` attributes and the label `for` attribute is empty so this fails on both counts. There is no **fieldName** attribute - you can use a `data-fieldName` instead.

Comment: From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) - `"The HTMLSelectElement.checkValidity() method checks whether the element has any constraints and whether it satisfies them. If the element fails its constraints, the browser fires a cancelable invalid event at the element, and then returns false"` these input elements have no constraints applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made changes in your JS code WITHOUT touching the HTML code, assuming that you want to keep the HTML code untouched.
While I removed the checkValidity() function as it really works on basic form only, I added 3 choses in your JS code:

- allFilled array to track if all inputs are filled or not (with 0 being empty input and 1 filled input)
- index in your forEach to detect which input
- also allEqual function to check if allFilled array items are 1 or not.

Once again, your JS code might work if the HTML code is touched, making the form really basic one, and vice versa, but I made changes for JS as it might serve to your needs

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let allFilled = []; // This will be your track array to track if all inputs are filled or not

inputs.forEach((input, index) => { // Added index here to detect which input which is.
  allFilled.push(0); // Push 0 in allFilled Track Array for every input there is in HTML code.
  input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if(e.target.value !== ""){ 
      allFilled[index] = 1 // Change the value of input statut in the AllFilled track array to indicate that it isn't empty one
    }
    else{
      allFilled[index] = 0 // Change the value of input statut in the AllFilled track array to indicate that the input is empty
    }
    allEqual(allFilled); // For every change in every input; the function allEqual is executed, the function checks if every input status in allFilled array is 1
  })
  /* Added the next lines of Code */
  if(input.getAttribute('name') === "firstName[0]") {
    input.setAttribute('value', 'Marius');
    allFilled[index] = 1;
  }
  if(input.getAttribute('name') === "lastName[0]") {
    input.setAttribute('value', 'Marius');
    allFilled[index] = 1;
  }
  if(input.getAttribute('name') === "email[0]") {
    input.setAttribute('value', 'marius@waha.com');
    allFilled[index] = 1;
  }
})


const allEqual = (array) => {
  if(array.every(val => val === 1)){
    document.querySelector('.message').classList.remove('d-none');
  } 
  else {
    document.querySelector('.message').classList.add('d-none')
  }
}
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="participants-data">
    <div class="form-content-holder">
      <div class="js-form-content form-content">
        <div class="participant-index">Participant</div>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="firstName[0]" fieldName="firstName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName[0]" fieldName="lastName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Last Name</label>
          <input type="email" name="email[0]" fieldName="email" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="js-form-content form-content">
        <div class="participant-index">Participant</div>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="firstName[1]" fieldName="firstName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName[1]" fieldName="lastName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Last Name</label>
          <input type="email" name="email[1]" fieldName="email" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="js-form-content form-content">
        <div class="participant-index">Participant</div>
        <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" name="firstName[2]" fieldName="firstName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName[2]" fieldName="lastName" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Last Name</label>
          <input type="email" name="email[2]" fieldName="email" class="input-participant-data">
          <label for="">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message d-none">Validated</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
Your code works, with the exception of one thing: the first three fields are always completed if the user is logged in and the validation stops working.

Here is an updated mockup Pen with what I'm trying to say: https://codepen.io/make96/pen/rNKVwgy

Comment: Like this only works if I delete what's inside first three auto-completed fields and fill them again.

Comment: I edited the code based on what you commented, all I did was adding the new lines at the end of forEach function with some line for each input to mark them as filled up statut in allFilled Array, if that's what you wanted, please mark it as Best answer, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You have inverted your condition, try the same code with the `!` removed in your condition